# What is Thread model, when we type 'clang --version'?

Tags: clang

```
Ubuntu clang version 14.0.0-1ubuntu1
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix  
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

In this text what is Thread model?
Is there many version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thread model in the output of "clang --version" is "posix". The Thread model refers to the specific threading implementation used by the Clang compiler. In this case, the posix thread model adheres to the POSIX thread standard (pthreads), which provides a standardized API for creating and managing threads.

There are no multiple versions of the thread model itself. The thread model represents a particular approach to handling threads and is not typically associated with version numbers. However, different versions of the Clang compiler may introduce changes or improvements related to thread handling, but those changes are separate from the thread model itself.